# Component won't render within NavigatorIOS - React Native

Tags: ios, reactjs, native

I can't get this simple NavigatorIOS test to work. The console log in My View triggeres, and I can get it to render if I skip the NavigatorIOS component, and render MyView directly. However, when MyView is triggered from a component within the NavigatorIOS component, it won't render anything else than 'My NavigatorIOS test'.

```
var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  NavigatorIOS,
  Text,
  View,
} = React;


 var navigation = React.createClass ({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS
            initialRoute={{
              component: MyView,
              title: 'My NavigatorIOS test',
              passProps: { myProp: 'foo' },
      }}/>
    );
  },
});


var MyView = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    console.log('My View render triggered');
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Hello there, welcome to My View
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
});


var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  }
});


AppRegistry.registerComponent('navigation', () => navigation);
```

Answer (score 62):

I had a similar problem. I added the following to my Stylesheet:

```
...
wrapper: {
  flex: 1,
}...
```

and then gave the `NavigatorIOS` component the `wrapper` style. That fixed the issue.

Comment: @mrborgen This would be a nice and neat answer. You don't you go ahead and mark this one?

Comment: There is nothing magic about 'wrapper'. Indeed, the samples pass ```style = {{flex: 1}}``` to the NavigatorIOS JSX.

Definitely subtle though. It would be nice for this to be called out as compulsory.

Answer (score 18):

Add the container style to NavigatorIOS, it needs to be flex:1 to show the child component properly ( I had the same issue).

Comment: I just tried, but then I just get a white screen. The Navigator header is gone too... Do you know why?

Comment: Thanks. How did you even think to do that? Do you have any idea why?

Comment: React native styling uses the flexbox model with a few changes, the flex: 1 property is simply telling the component to use all of the available space. Its similar to saying 100% height in this instance.

Answer (score 9):

I ran into the same issue, my mistake was in the styles :

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  }
});
```

I had to remove `justifyContent` and `alignItems` from there. Problem solved for me.

Comment: This worked for me, looks like you were following the react-native tutorials on egghead.io :P

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. Turned out I had to add some margin to the top of the view inside the MyView component.

Try this:

```
var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  NavigatorIOS,
  Text,
  View,
} = React;


 var navigation = React.createClass ({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS
            style={styles.container}
            initialRoute={{
              component: MyView,
              title: 'My NavigatorIOS test',
              passProps: { myProp: 'foo' },
      }}/>
    );
  },
});


var MyView = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    console.log('My View render triggered');
    return (
        <View style={styles.wrapper}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Hello there, welcome to My View
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
});


var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  wrapper: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    marginTop: 80
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  }
});


AppRegistry.registerComponent('navigation', () => navigation);
```

Comment: MyView is not displaying in navigation, only navigation is displaying

Comment: This is the only answer that helped me. Important is the style.container in NavigatorIOS.

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same problem. For me, that is the style problem. I create and use a new style property containerNV for NavigatorIOS. That solved my problem.

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  containerNV: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#05FCFF',
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue too (stupidly) as I'd given the NavigatorIOS a background colour, which meant it covered up the actual component inside it for some reason.

Comment: No... background should mean behind the component. I think you were fine. In native iOS the navigator doesn't really even have a view.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I use Navigator , and nothing help of up answers.
So I use **this.forceUpdate();** to force Update in button press function

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Nothing was rendering inside my main screen. After 2 hours I decided to remove the `<View>` element I was wrapping my navigator with, and suddenly everything worked.

In a nutshell, I went from this:

```
<View>
  <NavigatorIOS
    style={styles.container}
    initialRoute={{
      component: MainPage,
      title: 'MainPage',
    }}/>
</View>
```

to this

```
<NavigatorIOS
  style={styles.container}
  initialRoute={{
    component: MainPage,
    title: 'MainPage',
}}/>
```